# Creating UIImage with Data gives wrong CGImage resolution

Tags: swift, uiimage, cgimage

I need to convert a RAW image to JPEG and then apply some calculations to the image.

I need the image in both CGImage and UIImage formats.

For some reason, image resolution is correct when it comes to UIImage, but for underlying CGImage resolution is 3x too big.

Why does that happen? How can I make the correct size for CGImage?

```
    // original RAW image: (3504.0, 2336.0)
    let imageUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "IMG_3136", withExtension: "CR2")!
    let ciImage = CIFilter(imageURL: imageUrl).outputImage!
    let uiImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)
    let data = uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.92)!
    let recreatedUiImage = UIImage(data: data, scale: UIScreen.main.scale)!
    let cgImage = recreatedUiImage.cgImage!
    let cgImageSize = CGSize(width: cgImage.width, height: cgImage.height)
    print(recreatedUiImage.size) // (3504.0, 2336.0) CORRECT
    print(cgImageSize) // (10512.0, 7008.0) WRONG
```

Comment: Use `uiImage.scale` instead of `UIScreen.main.scale`.

Comment: `recreatedUiImage.size` gives you the ***point size*** not the ***pixel size***.

Comment: @DonMag you want to say that pixel size of the RAW image is 10512x7008? Every editor tells me that it's 3504x2336? Are they wrong?

Comment: @xinatanil - no... your RAW image (data) is evidently `3504 x 2336` ... but with this line: `let recreatedUiImage = UIImage(data: data, scale: UIScreen.main.scale)!` you are saying *"create a `UIImage` **at  `UIScreen.main.scale`**"*. If you're on a `@3x` scale device, that will generate a `10512 x 7008` *pixel* image (on a `@2x` scale device, you'll get a `7008 x 4672` *pixel* image). But `print(recreatedUiImage.size)` will output the **point size**.

Comment: @xinatanil - as HangerRash commented... Use `uiImage.scale` instead of `UIScreen.main.scale`